# jQuery replace with

Tags: jquery

I have the following html tag:

```
<a class="save action_btn" onclick="return false;">Save</a>
```

and the code:

```
$(".save").live('click', function() {
                            $.post("update.php", {uid: my_uid, save: "yes", mid: "<?php echo $mid; ?>"}, function(){
                                    $(this).replaceWith('<a class="action_btn x saved" onclick="return false;">Saved</a>');
                                }
                            );
                 });
```

However, why is it not changing the html tag?

Comment: are you sure that the POST is working ? I`ve tried it here: http://jsfiddle.net/sPbRZ/ , but without the POST and is working ...

Comment: I did put an alert inside the function that calls back after post and it executes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's cause you are erasing the element from 'itself'. You need a small delay, like this:

```
$(".save").live('click', function() {
    var $btn = $(this);
    $.post("update.php", {uid: my_uid, save: "yes", mid: "<?php echo $mid; ?>"}, function(){           
       setTimeout(function(){
           $btn.replaceWith('<a class="action_btn x saved" onclick="return false;">Saved</a>');   
       }, 100);

    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: The delay (`setTimeout`) is necessary only if the ajax request is synchronous. This could be happening if there has been a call to `$.ajaxSetup({async: true});`

Comment: Analizing my code, this case doesn't need delay. But, if there wouldn't be the asyncronous ajax call, it would be mandatory, so i'll let it like it's now in case someone needs it.

Comment: setTimeout has nothing to do with the fix.
`var $btn = $(this);` is what fixes it. See feelnoway's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a closure as shown below:

```
$(".save").live('click', function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $.post("update.php", {uid: my_uid, save: "yes", mid: "<?php echo $mid; ?>"}, function(){
       $this.replaceWith('<a class="action_btn x saved" onclick="return false;">Saved</a>');
   });
});
```

Comment: was gonna say... i don't think $(this) refers to the correct element within the ajax callback...you have to save it beforehand, as this answer suggests

Answer (score 0):

- Inside of the callback function from the `$.post` call, the `this` keyword is no longer the anchor tag. You can read about how JS handles `this` [here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/), but suffice it to say that you need to store the `this` value from before the call to `$.post` in a variable and use it inside of the callback.
- No need to have an onclick handler in your HTML and return false. Instead, just pull in the `event` object in your click callback and call `preventDefault`.

HTML:

```
<a class="save action_btn">Save</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".save").live('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $.post("update.php", {uid: my_uid, save: "yes", mid: "<?php echo $mid; ?>"}, function(){
    $this.replaceWith('<a class="action_btn x saved" onclick="return false;">Saved</a>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

provide div tag with id and try
`

```
<div id="replaceid"><a class="save action_btn" onclick="return false;">Save</a></div>
```

$(".save").live('click', function() {
                            $.post("update.php", {uid: my_uid, save: "yes", mid: ""}, function(){
                                    $('#replaceid').replaceWith(`'<a class="action_btn x saved" onclick="return false;">Saved</a>`');
                                }
                            );
                 });

`